Project not going to plan - what should I have done better?
I started working on this project about 3 months ago. The project was proposed by team A. It should have been a project from team B, where they have the expertise (and have about 20 people who works on similar type of things). However, their relationships are bad so they approached my manager and my manager agreed that I should spend 40% of my time working on it. There is an intern from team A who also works on this project. There are two people from team A who are sort of overlooking the project and providing ideas. Previously I have no experience in the area this project was in.
The team A who came up with the project had some idea about how to go ahead with it. We tried what they suggested initially - however, it turns out what they suggested is not really feasible due to the amount of work involved / missing data. We were stuck and for a few weeks we had no catch up. During this time, I did not work on it. Bearing in mind, at the beginning, there were weeks when I spent 100% of my time working on this project. I think this is not unreasonable.
Yesterday we had a catch up meeting - it was quite clear that the people from team A who are driving the project (as in they offer ideas, but not the modelling) was trying to place blame on me. The basically said since the idea they suggested did not work, it was up to me to think outside the box and come up with something.
It was apparent to me that this project is a big project - however as time moved along, I knew I did not have the skill set to do the job, if I only spent 40% of my time.
What I think I failed to do was that I did not alert my manager a few weeks ago when this project is going badly. I also had other things to do, which I know are more important for my manager / the business, especially given we had resignations in our team... I want some help in understanding.

what could I have done differently?
how to deflect the blame? I don't really care about being thrown under the bus as long as it does not affect my pay.
is there anyway I could have quietly distanced myself from this project?
what should I do now moving forward?


What is your responsibility for this project? Project manager? Other "administrative" job? Which? Simple execution (mechanical, software...)? This info is quite critical.

@virolino I am a quantitative modeller. I am not the project manager. The two guys who don't do work and only contribute ideas - they are meant to be managing it. The project was for them.

Moving Forward: Have you told the managers of both teams that the team will miss the deadline, and you need the mangers to take actions immediately ? The action would be to extend the deadline and let more experienced developers join the team.  --- Your question #4 is the most urgent one right now. The other 3 questions should be grouped into combined question for a different post. Otherwise, these 4 questions would be too many for 1 single post.


what could I have done differently?

Scope the work early and provide resource estimates. If the resource estimates exceed what the schedule asks for, elevate. If you feel that things are going off the rails, elevate to your manager as early as possible
Before engaging on a project (for real), everybody needs to agree on goals, requirements, success metric, schedule and resources in a written plan that can easily be tracked.

how to deflect the blame? I don't really care about being thrown under the bus as long as it does not affect my pay.

Have a talk with your manager. No one else is going to affect your pay. Ask the the same questions that you did here. If you didn't properly keep them in the loop you have indeed some blame.

is there anyway I could have quietly distanced myself from this project?

Open communication is better than doing anything quietly. If you felt that this project wasn't feasible, you should have told your manager and asked to either fix the problem or be taken officially of the project.

what should I do now moving forward?

See point one. Before engaging on a larger chunk of work insist on having written requirements, metrics, resource plan and schedule.

I've had this conversation now with my manager. We agreed that the scope of the work was not what we agree with that team at the beginning and outside our remit. He also agrees that we should discontinue it unless they are willing to commit more resources. I guess I should have made him aware when we were stuck a few weeks ago. However, this too was a bit tricky - he was off on holiday.
